# How to loop in blend4web with help of visual scripting?

Tags: javascript, loops, web, webgl, blender

I'm new to blend4web and i don't know how to loop in the engine without blocking it ?

I want to use all my js code not only logic nodes.
When a loop in my code it block the engine.

i have look around but did not find usefull information can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure for looping in a blend4web project is quite a mess at first but very intutive when you know it.
it use the **logic nodes system** and the **js callback methode**.

---

### setting up the logical loop

this is the easiest part, create the logical loop is purely made with logic nodes.
here a exemple :[image]

the loop for the js code is were the JS Callback node is, this will allow use to loop trough the js without blocking the engine.

the Select methode will just be here for starting the loop when we click the cube.

---

### The js callback nodes made in code

So now we have a loop but nothing to use. Just go to your file project and open the js file.

we **HAVE** to import the logic nodes modules to set up the js callback nodes set up earlier:

```
var m_logic = require("logic_nodes");
```

after that we have to setup the js callback nodes in the code.

for now we will setup them in *init_cb()*

```
function init_cb(canvas_elem, success) {

    [...]

    m_logic.append_custom_callback("loveBlend", loveBlend);

    load();
}
```

the append_custom_callback is the way blend4web link js callback nodes and js function. this is case sensitive so watch out.

---

### Make a function for the loop

after setting up everything we can now start writing the function.

```
function loveBlend()
{
    console.log("Blend4web is awesome");
}
```

this one is really simple but you can do many more things than printing text int the console.

---

### other Exemple

This exemple is 3D math function visualizer here the logical tree :

[image]

[And here a pastebin for the code](https://pastebin.com/G7AATVWq)

if you want to see the full project, [download it](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7coq3o041edl40i/cube_graphe_project.zip/file) and try it on firefox, chrome and blend4web exported projects don't work well as of now.

---

### Common error

if you project don't work be sure to check if :

- you have save you .blend file and re-export your file
- you have set the right logic tree as active
- check spelling error

if you are exporting be sure to test you project in firefox.